# Rails: Files get filled with trailing whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-5, puts

The problem I have is that whenever I save some values to a File, Rails magically adds trailing whitespace to each line.

*For example when I read the file the initaial content got manipulated:*

`"cv"` => `"cv\r\n"`

`"cv\r\nvd"` => `"cv\r\n\r\nvd\r\n"`

Here is how I create my File:

```
File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
    f.truncate(0)
    f.puts value
end
```

I appreciate each help!

Answer (score 1):

## Theory

If `value` doesn't have a trailing newline, `value.chomp` won't change anything because the newline doesn't come from `value` but from [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-puts) :

> Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not
>   already end with a newline sequence.

[`IO#write`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-write) is the method you're looking for.

Finally, `f.truncate(0)` isn't needed because `w+` stands for :

> "w+" Read-write, truncates existing file to zero length
>        or creates a new file for reading and writing.

## Example

```
path = "test.txt"
value = 2

File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
    f.write value
end

p File.read(path)
```

returns :

```
"2"
```

With `puts` instead of `write`, it returns :

```
"2\n"
```

## Newlines inside the string ?

If for some reason, value is a String with newlines inside, `chomp` and `write` won't help. Use `gsub` to replace multiple newlines with just one :

```
path = "test.txt"
value = "Hello\r\n\r\nWorld\n\nLine #3\r\rLine #4"

File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
    f.write value.gsub(/\R+/,"\n")
end

p File.read(path)
#=> "Hello\nWorld\nLine #3\nLine #4"
```

If you want spaces instead of newlines :

```
f.write value.gsub(/\R+/," ")
```

Comment: hm. `f.write value` adds nothing to the file. `f.write(value)` adds the value to the file, but with trailing whitespace.

Comment: That's unexpected. What does `p value` return? Is value a method or a variable? Do you only have `f.write value` on the line?

Comment: `value` is a variable and it returns for example `gt\r\nki`. When I read the File created, I get: `gt\r\nnki`

Comment: So there's a newline *inside* `value`. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, that is what I get: `value` returns example `Hello\r\nWorld`. When I read the File created, I get: `Hello\r\n\r\nWorld`

Comment: The example just reproduces the general problem I have, when saving content with `\r\n` to a file

Comment: `puts` or `write` shouldn't change anything inside the string. You'll have to show more code than this, and how value is initialized.

Comment: Ok, now it gets complicated. I use CodeMirror inside a textarea while using a form which sends a post request on submit to another controller action. The value of the textarea field gets inserted into the form input. I checked the parameters of the post request and at that point everything is ok with the permitted content.

Comment: In the controller action I just run the code, I gave in the question.

Comment: One question, is `A\r\nB` like `A break B` or like `A break break B`?

Comment: It's just one break for Windows : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130974/discussion-between-eric-duminil-and-jonhue).